# jQuery selector help - or, and

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to create a jQuery selector that will do something like this:

```
(.a OR .b OR .c) AND (.x OR .y OR .z)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
$("(.a,.b,.c)(.x,.y,.z)")
```

I need it in a single selector so that I can use it as a filter in the Isotope plugin. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html

Here's an example of what I want to achieve: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html, only I want to be able to select red AND blue. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible for a general case, I suspect. You can do it with two selections: `$('.a, .b, .c').filter('.x, .y, .z')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By expanding the `AND` (it's basically a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)), this is equivalent to:

```
.a.x OR .a.y OR .a.z OR .b.x OR .b.y OR .b.z OR .c.x OR .c.y OR .c.z
```

so just replace the `OR`s with `,`s and you've got a selector:

```
$('.a.x, .a.y, .a.z, .b.x, .b.y, .b.z, .c.x, .c.y, .c.z')
```

Comment: This can get very long if there are many options, but on the plus side it will perform better than my solution below (since it can benefit from the browser's native selectors, something that AFAIK will not happen when using `:not()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (i.e. instead of expanding your logic formula, you use a double negation to transform an AND into an OR):

```
:not(:not(.a, .b, .c), :not(.x, .y, .z))
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDFdd/). The transformations I'm applying are:

```
a AND b ==> not(not(a AND b))
        ==> not((not a) OR (not b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an expression that returns a string

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sq4xF/

```
var parents=['a','b','c']
var kids=['c','d','e']

var selector=[];
for ( i=0; i<parents.length; i++){
   var sel='.'+parents[i] ;
    for (j=0; j<kids.length; j++){
       selector.push( sel+"."+kids[j]);  /* add space if kids are desecendents, "AND" was not clear in question*/
    }
}

$("'"+ selector.join()+"'").css('color','red')
```